# How do you find a delimited/isolated substring with string.contains?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to parse out and identify some values from strings that I have in a list.

I am using `string.Contains` to identify the value im looking for, but I am getting hits even if the value is surrounded by other text. How can I make sure I only get a hit if the value is isolated?

**Example parse:**

Looking for value = `"302"`

```
string sale = 
  "199708. (30), italiano, delim fabricata modella, serialNumber302. tnr F18529302E.";

var result = sale.ToLower().Contains(”302”));
```

In this example I will get a hit for `"serialNumber302"` and `"F18529302E"`, which in the context is incorrect since I only want a hit if it finds “302” isolated, like “dontfind302 shouldfind 302”.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify why `serialNumber302` is correct while `F18529302E` is not.

Comment: Perhaps OP means that neither `serialNumber302` nor `F18529302E` should be found when searching for `302`.

Comment: Updated question to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try Regex, you can define a word boundary using `\b`:

```
string sale = 
  "199708. (30), italiano, delim fabricata modella, serialNumber302. tnr F18529302E.";

bool result = Regex.IsMatch(sale, @"\b302\b"); // false

sale = "A string with 302 isolated";

result = Regex.IsMatch(sale, @"\b302\b"); // true
```

So 302 will only be found if it is at the start of the string, at the end of the string, or if it is surrounded by non-word characters i.e. not a-z A-Z 0-9 or _

Comment: This does not work for some reason, it returns false on both lines. The syntax seems correct, can you get it to work? Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3eOlYL

Comment: Ah yes, `\b` is being interpreted by .NET as a backspace character, so you need to make the string verbatim to keep it as a Regex word boundary. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: From the comments I realiſed that it waſn't clear whether or not "serialNum302" ſhould get a hit. I aſſumed ſo in this anſwer.

I ſee a few eaſy ways you could do this:

1) If the input is always a number as in the example, one option would be to only ſearch for ſubﬅrings not ſurrounded by more numbers, by examining all the reſults of an initial ſearch and comparing their neighboring characters againﬅ the ﬅring "0123456789". I *really* don't think this is the beﬅ option though, becauſe ſooner or later it's goïng to break when it miſinterprets one of the other bits of data.

2) If the ﬅring sale always has the ſeriäl number in the format "serialNumber[Num]", inﬅead of juﬅ looking for Num, look for "serialNumber" + Num, as this is leſs likely to be meſſed up with the other data.

3) From your ﬅring, it looks like you have a ﬅandardized format that's beïng introduced to the ſyﬅem. In this caſe, parſe it in a ﬅandardized way, e.g. by ſplitting it into ſubﬅrings at the commas, then parſing each ſubﬅring differently as it requires.